# TinyMCE is not loading when PHP GET Sent

Tags: php, get, tinymce, tinymce-4

TinyMCE loads properly unless I go to the page in this format `example.com?m=abc`

As soon as I send PHP GET through the code to the page and load it that way, TinyMCE does not load.

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: How does your code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @progsource!!

I wanted to load TinyMCE files only when write.php is open but then if I send get data to the page then TinyMCE doesn't load...

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/write.php") { ?>TinyMCE Code <?php } ?>
```

This was the code broke it.